# Issue Creating Several Scripts with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, sql-scripts

I am using postgres to create several INSERT scripts to insert data from one database to another.

The statement is giving me an error for invalid syntax for integer.

Here is the script I am trying to run

```
select 'INSERT INTO public."HoldingMasters"(
    "AccountID", "AssetID", "CreatedDate", "DateAcquired", "GainsLongTerm", "LotNumber", "Managed", "ModifiedDate", "Sweep", "UID", "Units", "UnitsPledged", "IsModified", "ModifiedCount")
    SELECT ' + CAST("AccountID" as integer) + ',' + CAST("AssetID" as integer) + ',' + "CreatedDate" + ',' + "DateAcquired" + ',' + "GainsLongTerm" + ',' + CAST("LotNumber" as integer) + ',' + "Managed" + ',' + "ModifedDate" + ',' + "Sweep" + ',' + CAST("UID" as integer) + ',' + "Units" + ',' + ',' + "UnitsPledged" + ',' + "IsModifed" + ',' + CAST("ModifiedCount" as integer) +
    'WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT "UID" from "HoldingMasters" where "UID" = ' + CAST("UID" as integer) +')'
    as script from "HoldingMasters";
```

And this gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "INSERT INTO public."HoldingMasters"(
    "AccountID", "AssetID", "CreatedDate", "DateAcquired", "GainsLongTerm", "LotNumber", "Managed", "ModifiedDate", "Sweep", "UID", "Units", "UnitsPledged", "IsModified", "ModifiedCount")
    SELECT "
LINE 1: select 'INSERT INTO public."HoldingMasters"(
           ^
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 8
```

Several of these columns are integers and I am not sure what syntax to use to get them to cast properly in the INSERT statement within my scripts.

I have tried:

SUM(NULLIF("AccountID", '')::integer)

"AccountID"::integer

to_number - does not seem to work on my machine

I have run this INSERT statement by itself without any issue, it just seems to have troubles when within the "as script" generator. I have not seen anyone try this syntax within a script generator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`. The `+` is for adding numbers.

Comment: Unrelated, but: generating SQL strings is a lot easier if you use the `format()` function instead of concatenating string fragments

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, ahh thank seems to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, If you wouldn't mind could you give an example of how you would use format() on this following block?

select 'SELECT * from public."HoldingMasters" WHERE "AccountID" = ' || "AccountID" || '' as script from "HoldingMasters";

Comment: It seems you don't want to replace those column names with their values, but just put the column names into the query, so why don't you just use `SELECT "AccountID", "AssetID", ... from ...`? What exactly should the generated INSERT statement look like?

Comment: No I am trying to replace their values from the columns. I have 2 databases both with the same schema and I am trying to insert the values from one database into the other.

To do this I am creating 1,000+ insert statements and I am using this script to generate all of those inserts by replacing the columns with the data from database A then running each insert in database B.

Comment: Here is a working example of what I want

`INSERT INTO public."HoldingMasters"("AccountID", "AssetID", "CreatedDate", "DateAcquired", "GainsLongTerm", "LotNumber", "Managed", "ModifiedDate", "Sweep", "UID", "Units", "UnitsPledged", "IsModified", "ModifiedCount")SELECT 318,1000886,'2018-07-11 16:00:04.854','2009-07-19 00:00:00',false,1,true,'2018-07-11 16:00:04.854',false,1000088,0.00,,0.000000000,true,3 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT "UID" from "HoldingMasters" where "UID" = 1000088)`